# RefreshToken through Google OAuth in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, access-token, refresh-token

I'm developing a Flutter app for the web and I need to get the authorization of the user to access his Google Calendar and then create events through Cloud Functions. The problem I'm facing is in using the flutter package [`google_sign_in`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) and [`google_sign_in_web`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web), because I could actually use the `signIn()` method to retrieve the `accessToken` and the `refreshToken`, but it is deprecated in favor of `renderButton()`, as said in the docs.

I'm not so expert in OAuth process and its implementation in Flutter, so I appreciate any advice on it.

(I need the two tokens so I can save them in Firestore)